# CAML query where date field is greater than another date field

Tags: development, caml-query

Is it possible to write a CAML query that uses another field as the Value part of the filter?

For example in SQL it would look like this:

WHERE Field1 > Field2

This was by best guess but it is not working:

```
<Gt><FieldRef Name='NoticeSentDate'/><Value Type='DateTime'><FieldRef Name='NoticeDate'/></Value></Gt>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it cannot be done in CAML. If you have to use CAML, the recommended approach is created a calculated column such as `=DATEDIF([NoticeSentDate], [NoticeDate],"d")`. Your CAML query would then look for values greater than 0 in the calculated column.

Check out this page for more examples of date calculations in calculated columns:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx

If you're not stuck using CAML queries, let me know what other options are available (such as AJAX or LINQ to SharePoint) and I'll try to help.